# Celery crontab on daily basis

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery-beat

I have run the celery tasks based on crontab for every minutes and 12.30 pm on every day. every minute is working perfectly. But the daily tasks of every day 12.30 pm is not working. Any suggestions ?

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'task-second': {
    'task': 'app1.tasks.add_schedular',
    'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
},
'mail-check': {
    'task': 'app1.tasks.mail_schedular',
    'schedule': crontab(hour=12,minute=25),
}
}
```

Comment: the second schedule is valid, what timezone did you set up in your settings?

Comment: it is UTC only brother

Comment: If i set the mail-check task also for every minutes it works . But according to my condition its not worked

Comment: If your configuration is in UTC, then expect it to run at 12:25PM UTC (12:25 UTC). So if your local timezone is different e.g. UTC+8, then expect it to run at 08:25PM UTC+8 (20:25 UTC+8). Keep in mind that **both** your celery scheduler and celery worker must be running when the scheduled time comes.